# how to get the row values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to get the email id from the users table from database in php, But its getting the null value. I have only row in users table. how do i get the email id column in php?

here is my table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Here is my script

```
                    $connection = db::factory('mysql');
                    $query="SELECT email from users";
                    $row=mysql_query($query);
                    $results=mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_NUM);
                    $adminemail=$results[3];
```

Comment: It's confusing when you write "trying to get the email id", when `email` and `id` are two different columns. Which do you want, the email or the id?

Comment: `while ($results= mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s  Password: %s  Email: %s", $results[0], $results[1], $results[2], $results[3]);  
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "SELECT email from users" which will return only one column.

So access it using `$adminemail=$results['email'];`

Answer (score 1):

this your answer

```
    $results=mysql_fetch_array($row);
    $adminemail=$results['email'];
```

Comment: see second parameter, it's mentioned `MYSQL_NUM` not `MYSQL_ASSOC`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $adminemail=$results['email'];
```

Should be the answer to your question. You poorly phrased your question. You're returning the email, not an ID. So you need to put 'email' instead of the number of the column it would be in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT `email` FROM `users`";
```

because you are querying just one column (email), and assuming you are returning just one row:

```
list($email) = mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_NUM);

echo $email;
```

If you are returning multiple rows, you can put it in a while loop

```
while (list($email) = mysql_fetch_array($row, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo $email;
}
```